# subclassResponsibility sender selector stuck

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

subclassResponsibility sender selector stuck even when subclasses have the method implemented.

I think the argument may cause this happen but is it?

and could anyone tell us why?

in abstract class we have this

```
fromString: aString
    "init with a string"

    ^self subclassResponsibility
```

and I am running this:

```
unit := (Units new fromString: aString)
```

then error occurs.

In which **Units** is the abstract class.

Travis Griggs's current approach could remove the error yet

are there doubledispatch for the instance creation method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kind of shy on details up there, but it looks like it's doing exactly what you told it to.

The expression `Units new` returned a new `Units` instance and then you sent `fromString:` to that. Which you've implemented to return the result of sending `subclassResponsibility`.

If `Units` were truly an *abstract* class, I wouldn't have expected you to instantiate it (you don't generally send `new` to abstract classes, unless you're also messing with the behavior of `new`).

So I would have expected you to do something like:

```
unit := (YourRealSubclass new fromString: aString)
```

And that `YourRealSubclass` has a real implementation of `fromString:`